# jQuery add a class to the selected parent, not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have my markup like this

```
    <table class="processed">
        <tr class="translated">
            <td class="meta-data">Subscription </td>
            <td class="test_staus">Lorem</td>
            <td class="total_price"><input type="text" value="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="proofreaded">
            <td class="meta-data">Subscription </td>
            <td class="test_staus">Lorem</td>
            <td class="total_price"><input type="text" value="7"></td>
        </tr>   
</table>
```

As you can see I have two input fields in both rows. So I want that when I will start typing in a input text box then it will add a class to its parent tr class. For that I made my js like this

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
          jQuery('body').keyup('td.total_price input',function() {
           var Selected = jQuery(this).closest('tr');
          Selected.addClass('selected');
       });
    });
    </script>
```

But its not working at all. The fiddle link is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5ck37nmm/) as you can see.
So can someone tell me how to add a class just a parent of the selected. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Your class 'selected`. Can you post the CSS of that?

Answer (score 3):

there is a syntax error in event binding, use this:

```
jQuery('body').on('keyup', 'td.total_price input',function() {
```

---

There is no need to use delegated events like above if you have static elements on page. You can simply use direct event binding like as suggested in other answers as well:

```
 jQuery('td.total_price input').on('keyup', function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for the event is incorrect. This works fine:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    jQuery('td.total_price input').keyup(function () {
        jQuery(this).closest('tr').addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/5ck37nmm/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
   jQuery(document).on('keyup', 'td.total_price input', function() {
        var Selected = jQuery(this).closest('tr');
        Selected.addClass('selected');
   });
```

Or better still, unless the table content is added after DOM ready:

```
   jQuery('td.total_price input').keyup(function() {
        var Selected = jQuery(this).closest('tr');
        Selected.addClass('selected');
   });
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/5ck37nmm/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input").on("keyup",function(){
    $(this).parent(".total_price").parent("tr").addClass("selected");
});
```